# How to convert a string read from input to a list of lists in prolog

Tags: string, list, prolog

I'm trying to write a program that converts from Mayan to Arabic numerals and vice versa in prolog. Although I'm still running into some trouble I've managed to get it mostly working. I'm just wondering how if I read for example:

```
....| 0 .| |||
```

from a user input, how can I convert it to a list like this:

```
L = [ ['.','.','.','.','|'], [0], ['.','|'], ['|','|','|'] ]
```

I have an algorithm written getting from L to the arabic value, but I have no clue how to convert that string into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100583/using-a-prolog-dcg-to-split-a-string). The code I've written there splits a Prolog string on spaces to generate a list of atoms. With a small modification, you can alter the code to create strings instead of atoms. Here is the relevant code from the previous post, with the necessary modification for your case:

```
data([A|As]) --> 
    spaces(_), 
    chars([X|Xs]), 
    {string_to_list(A, [X|Xs])},  %% Using string_to_list/2 instead
    spaces(_), 
    data(As).
data([]) --> [].

chars([X|Xs]) --> char(X), !, chars(Xs).
chars([]) --> [].

spaces([X|Xs]) --> space(X), !, spaces(Xs).
spaces([]) --> [].

space(X) --> [X], {code_type(X, space)}. 
char(X) --> [X], {\+ code_type(X, space)}.
```

In your example, you'd take a Prolog string containing your example like `"....| 0 .| |||"` and run the above code using the built-in `phrase/2`, like so:

```
?- phrase(data(NumeralList), "....| 0 .| |||").
NumeralList = ["....|", "0", ".|", "|||"]
```

Note that I've tested this on [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) and it works, but if you're using a different Prolog implementation, it mightn't support DCGs or the built-ins I've used.

If you were after a result which is *precisely* like what you've described as `L` above, you can modify the code further to return the list [X|Xs] directly in the `data` clause (removing the sub-goal `{string_to_list(A, [X|Xs])},`), and change the last predicate `char` to the following:

```
char(C) --> [X], {\+ code_type(X, space), atom_codes(C,[X])}.
```

Running this gives:

```
?- phrase(data(L), "....| 0 .| |||").
L = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '|'], ['0'], ['.', '|'], ['|', '|', '|']]
```

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the modified code which generates the above result in full:

```
data([[X|Xs]|As]) --> 
    spaces(_), 
    chars([X|Xs]), 
    spaces(_), 
    data(As).
data([]) --> [].

chars([X|Xs]) --> char(X), !, chars(Xs).
chars([]) --> [].

spaces([X|Xs]) --> space(X), !, spaces(Xs).
spaces([]) --> [].

space(X) --> [X], {code_type(X, space)}. 
char(C) --> [X], {\+ code_type(X, space), atom_codes(C,[X])}.
```

Comment: Yes I did want it precisely as described with L, I'm playing around with the data clause now, it keeps failing at the first space, troubleshooting now. How exactly would the code look if you changed it accordingly? Sorry I'm not familiar with some of the things used above so I'm trying to learn it as I troubleshoot.

Comment: I've added the code (I thought I explained the code alterations clearly... perhaps something else is wrong? Are you using SWI-Prolog? What errors are you getting?)

Comment: +1 @sharky: Wouldn't it be nice to have some convention about how a nonterminal handles the base case? So here, you are using the eager version for, e.g. `spaces//1`.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I was using SWI-Prolog, I had a minor error. Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3):

In SWI-Prolog there is a builtin that almost gives what you need:

```
?- atom_chars('....| 0 .| |||', L).
L = ['.', '.', '.', '.', '|', ' ', '0', ' ', '.'|...].
```

Splitting on spaces can be done with another builtin, used in 'reverse' mode:

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', '....| 0 .| |||').
L = ['....|', '0', '.|', '|||'].
```

Then we can combine these using maplist:

```
?- atomic_list_concat(L, ' ', '....| 0 .| |||'), maplist(atom_chars,L,G).
L = ['....|', '0', '.|', '|||'],
G = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '|'], ['0'], ['.', '|'], ['|', '|', '|']].
```

G it's very similar to what you need, just handle the '0'...

Comment: Wow this is even simpler. I haven't tried it out yet but it's cleaner.

Comment: Haha, nice, +1. I'd put the built-ins aside because OP hadn't mentioned SWI-Prolog, and my brain kicked into DCG mode, though I ended up using them anyhow ;-)