# Creating a list from user input using stop chars

Tags: prolog

How can I create a list of words from the user input?

Example:

```
?- readInput(L). 
|: this is an input. this will not be considered

L=[This, is, an, input, '.']
```

I want the character . or ? to be the end of the sentence, so everything after it will not be in the list and both stop chars must be inside the list.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is basically a tokenizer, for which [this link](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/aipp/lecture_slides/13_String_Manipulation.ppt) can help you. In summary, you should first convert the user input into ASCII code and then recursively parse the code list, treating comma and space characters separately.

If you're using SWI-Prolog, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353000/reading-a-user-input-string-in-prolog) can also help you.